# Import spring framework into eclipse error

Tags: eclipse, spring, import, frameworks

after i imported spring framework into eclipse,i have encountered 2 errors.

1. The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.springframework.asm.Type. Fix the build path then try building this project.
2. The type org.springframework.asm.Type cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: You are missing some jars.

Comment: How did you import spring framework to eclipse? download and add jars or using dependency management tool like maven. ?

Comment: I use gradle to complie spring framework to eclipse project,then import it into eclipse.I have fixed some errors,just these two errors left.They happen in /spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scripting/config/ScriptBeanDefinitionParser.class.I have build path the org.springframework.asm jar,it has  org.springframework.asm.Type.